# JavaScript/jQuery Change Class of A Tag Specifically When Two Input Fields Are Both Filled In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="field text-left">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="text-left">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="text-left">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <a href="#" id="fullnameBtn" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

The above is in a multi-step form with other values and hidden panel.

I am trying to figure out how to remove the Class **disabled** from the a tag with id **fullnameBtn** only when both surname and name fields are entered using JavaScript or jQuery.

Can someone help on the right path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1-check if both the fields are filled
2- then remove the "selected" class

```
if($("name") && $("surname")){
  $("#fullnameBtn").removeClass("disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to toggle class [but still i guess you want to disable and enable the nextPage link for which you have to manually handle in disabled class]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // lets monitor the input of values for inputs you can use a class also
    $('input').on('input',function(){
       // added for bit of simplicity or you can directly get valuess
      var surname = $('#surname').val();
      var name = $('#name').val();
      if(surname != "" && name != "" )
      {
        // values seems filled remove class  
        $('#fullnameBtn').removeClass('disabled');
      }
      else
      {
        // user has emptied some input so add class again.
        $('#fullnameBtn').addClass('disabled');
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field text-left">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="text-left">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="text-left">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#" id="fullnameBtn" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
  </div>
 </div>  
                            </div>
```